# how can i convert a string column to a date type using apply() function

Tags: python, pandas

Although I have used another method i.e astype(datetime[ns]) and it worked, but I still want to know why this code gives an error

```
'''transaction['transaction_date'] = transaction['transaction_date'].apply([lambda x :datetime.strptime(x,"%y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")])'''
```

it gives this error message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-17fc8b725c4b> in <module>
----> 1 transaction['transaction_date'] = transaction['transaction_date'].apply([lambda x :datetime.strptime(x,"%y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")])

~\Anacondas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)

   3821         # dispatch to agg
   3822         if isinstance(func, (list, dict)):
-> 3823             return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwds)
   3824 
   3825         # if we are a string, try to dispatch

~\Anacondas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in aggregate(self, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   3686         # Validate the axis parameter
   3687         self._get_axis_number(axis)
-> 3688         result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
   3689         if result is None:
   3690 

~\Anacondas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    484         elif is_list_like(arg):
    485             # we require a list, but not an 'str'
--> 486             return self._aggregate_multiple_funcs(arg, _axis=_axis), None
    487         else:
    488             result = None

~\Anacondas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg, _axis)
    549         # if we are empty
    550         if not len(results):
--> 551             raise ValueError("no results")
    552 
    553         try:

ValueError: no results
```

Comment: sorry, this is my first time asking a question here, I know it looks messy

Comment: put your code in ``` (three backticks) ``` and for error messages use `>`.

Comment: Can you try: ```import datetime as dt
transaction['transaction_date'] =transaction['transaction_date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S'))```?